# unparsed line - 'LCONF_VERS ION = "6" '

Tags: raspberry-pi, bitbake, parse-error

I am trying to build **linux for the raspberry pi 3**, but when I give the bitbake command `bitbake rpi-basic-image` , I get the following error.

> "ERROR: ParseError at /../bblayers.conf:1: unparsed line: 'LCONF_VERS
>   = "6"' "

Trying to run someone else's walkthrough and have hit this.

Comment: Can you please provide bblayers.conf?

Comment: i could if i knew how to copy and paste into windows from an ubuntu virtual machine

Comment: Found the error is a missing file - which is there :/

Comment: Those quotes around the 6 look like smart quotes from Microsoft Word (or similar). Make sure you're using plain old `"`.